# Reindexing a Triple Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Suppose i have the following integral:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{4}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k}a_{n+2-k}b_{j}c_{k-j}x^{n+2}$$
I want to reindex to make the power of $x$ simply $x^n$, so I have to shift by 2.  Would I shift every index then and make the sum
$$\sum_{n=2}^{6}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{j=2}^{k}a_{n-k-2}b_{j-2}c_{(k-2)-(j-2)}x^{n}$$
$$=\sum_{n=2}^{6}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{j=2}^{k}a_{n-k-2}b_{j-2}c_{k-j}x^{n}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By shifting by $2$, the $n$'s should be replaced by $n - 2$. So the result is

$$\sum_{n = 2}^6 \sum_{k = 0}^{n-2} \sum_{j = 0}^k a_{n-k}b_jc_{k-j}x^n$$

Comment: I see now.  I had a feeling that reindexing by $n$ should only affect the $n$'s but then I had my sum above in the question and it seemed to be correct.  This is better though.  Thank you.