# Reindexing a Triple Sum with two parameters

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have the following triple summation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{r-3}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k}a_j b_{k+s-j}c_{n+t-k}x^{n+s+t}$$

I would like to reindex to have $n$ start at $s+t$ which will make my $x$ power $x^n$, not $x^{n+s+t}$.  Using the solution I received to a [similar question I posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142970/reindexing-a-triple-sum), my thought is that I have to change all $n$'s to $n-(s+t)$.  This yields

$$\sum_{n=s+t}^{r+s+t-3}\sum_{k=0}^{n-s-t}\sum_{j=0}^{k}a_j b_{k+s-j}c_{n-s\color{red}{-t+t}-k}x^{n}$$
$$\sum_{n=s+t}^{r+s+t-3}\sum_{k=0}^{n-s-t}\sum_{j=0}^{k}a_j b_{k+s-j}c_{n-s-k}x^{n}$$

I assume that there is no issue here, but with my parameter $t$ leaving the index, I was suspect that this was correct.  Can anyone verify that this reindexation is correct and that the method works in general regardless of the number of parameters?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct. The point is the inner sums create a sequence $A_n$, where $n$ is the index of the outer-most sum. So really, you're reindexing a single sum $\sum_{n = 0}^{r-3} A_nx^{n+s+t}$, which you can write $$\sum_{n = s + t}^{r + s + t - 3} A_{n-s-t}x^n$$ Writing out $A_{n-s-t}$ gives the formula the want.

Comment: thank you again.  I assumed it was correct and the approach you use simplifies things greatly, but when I saw the $t$ disappear, I just became a little suspect and decided to ask.  I appreciate the help.